# Vercel Type error: Module '"../../interfaces"' has no exported member 'IUser'

Tags: mongodb, next.js, vercel

I'm getting the following error when trying to deploy my project in VERCEL, I don't know what's wrong with my code since it runs perfectly in local, I even ran yarn build and it gives no errors at all, triple checked my code and there actually is that interface IUser and it's exported and declared properly, I'll attach my repo, and I'll be thanksfull with any help to solve this.

[My Repo](https://github.com/jlescalonap/template-shop)

[Vercel error compared to local build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blHsi.png) < SEE the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by checking my github repo, when I was building the proyect I changed the name of a file but github didn't recognize that change and left the old name of the file in the repository, then Vercel was calling to a file that didn't exist, that was the problem, I solved by erasing the file from github and uploading it with the new name.